# Working with jagged arrays in jQuery template

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a jagged array like

```
var questions = [
    {
        qNo: 1, question: "This is first question",
        answer: "answer for question1",
        options: [["a) subopt1", " b) subopt2", "c) subopt3", "d) subopt4", "e) subopt5"] ,
            ["This is option2 for this question"],
            ["This is option2 for this question"]]
    }
```

I have created a jQuery template to render this questions array which has options array, note options array element 1 {suboptions} is another array. I would like to loop through the suboptions as well. I am able to loop through options but not suboptions. So far I have the template as

```
<script type="text/html" id="question-template">

    <div class="ques">
        <label>
            ${qNo}. ${question}
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="opt">
        <div class="has-error hide" id="divErr${qNo}">
            Please select an option for Question ${qNo}
        </div>
        {{each options}}
        <div class="mrgn">
            <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" VALUE="A" NAME="radio${qNo}" onclick="radioClick('${qNo}')">
            ${$value}<BR> **(Here I want to loop through values if it is an array)**
        </div>
        {{/each}}
        <div class="mrgn">
            <INPUT TYPE="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnAns${qNo}" onclick="btnAnsClick('${qNo}')" value="Show Answer" />
        </div>
        <div class="ans hide" id="divAns${qNo}">
            ${answer}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue, if it is of any help to others
here is the solution

```
<div class="ques">
    <label>
        ${qNo}. ${question}
    </label>
</div>
<div class="opt">
    <div class="has-error hide" id="divErr${qNo}">
        Please select an option for Question ${qNo}
    </div>
    {{each(i, option) options}}
    <div class="mrgn">
        <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" VALUE="A" NAME="radio${qNo}" onclick="radioClick('${qNo}')">
        {{each option }}
                ${$value}<br />
        {{/each}}<br />
    </div>
    {{/each}}
    <div class="mrgn">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnAns${qNo}" onclick="btnAnsClick('${qNo}')" value="Show Answer" />
    </div>
    <div class="ans hide" id="divAns${qNo}">
        ${answer}
    </div>
</div>
```